# Image Carousel HTML/JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please help.  I have an image carousel on my website.  When resizing the browser, the carousel adjusts accordingly, but the images and the caption text is being cut.  Would you please provide me with a feedback on how to make it responsive? Thank you in advance for your help.

```js
<script src="js/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
   $('#slides').slides({
       effect: 'fade',
    crossfade:true,
    fadeSpeed:1200,
    preload: true,
    preloadImage: 'images/loading.gif',
    play: 4000,
    pause: 2500,
    slideSpeed: 1000,
    hoverPause: false
   });
  });
</script>
```

```css
.slides_container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 459px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 0px auto;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 3px #E3E4E7;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 3px #E3E4E7;
}
.slides_container a {
 width: 100%;
 height: 459px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
}
.slides_container a img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.image_text {
 width: 600px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 55%;
 left: 30%;
 font-weight: bold;
 height: auto;
 padding: 20px;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: rgba(66,66,66,1.00);
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 50px;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 opacity: 0.7;
 filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* For IE8 and earlier */
 font-family: "Capsuula", san-serif;
 letter-spacing: 1.5px;
 border-radius: 8px;
}
.pagination {
 margin-top: 315px;
 margin-left: 930px;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 99;
 top: 297px;
 left: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
<ul class="pagination">
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="slides">
    <div class="slides_container">
      <div style="background:url(images/index-banner-1.png);">
        <div class="image_text">Caption 1 </div>
        <div><img class="slides-img" src="images/index-banner-1.png" alt="Slide-1"/></div>
      </div>
      <div style="background:url(images/index-banner-2.png);">
        <div class="image_text">Caption 2</div>
        <div><img class="slides-img" src="images/index-banner-2.png" alt="Slide-2"/></div>
      </div>
      <div style="background:url(images/index-banner-3.png);">
        <div class="image_text">Caption 3</div>
        <div><img class="slides-img" src="images/index-banner-3.png" alt="Slide-3"/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use this reference to understand [Responsive Design](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps)

Comment: If the width property is set to 100%, the image will be responsive and scale up and down:

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_image2